# Move C++ app with Boost from Linux to Windows with Visual Studio 6

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I made a small program with Boost in Linux 2 yrs ago. Now I want to make it work in Windows. I found there are few .a files in my libs folder. I am wondering how to make it works in Windows? do I need to build Boost in Windows to get library or I can download somewhere? I am using Visual Studio 6.

Comment: Everything else aside, I would concern that latest boost will work with VS6 in the first place

Comment: Boost does a great job of trying to keep it working on old compilers, but that compiler is *seriously* ick.

Comment: Visual C++ was published two years before the first C++ standard and thus its support for the current C++ version is very incomplete and broken. Upgrade to a compiler made in 2000's.

Comment: Can you change the title to be more descriptive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to recompile for different platforms. Coincidentally, I posted instructions on this [not long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274188/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-libboost-regex-vc90-mt-gd-1-42-lib/2274252#2274252).

I *hugely* recommend you *do not* use Visual Studio 6. It's very dated, and terribly non-conforming. You can get the newer versions for free, as Express. You won't be missing anything.

Comment: OK, I can use VS 2003, then how to set the build parameter?

Comment: should I uninstall my old VS6.0 and install the 2003? or just install it without uninstall my old 6.0?

Comment: @5YrsLater: They can live together. :)

Answer (score 2):

Many boost libraries are header-only, you don't need to link against anything to use them. Libraries such as `boost::filesystem` require you to build libs appropriate for your platform and link against them.

Precompiled boost for MSVC7,8,9 can be found [here](http://www.boostpro.com/download)  (in the hope that you follow GMan's advice and get rid of VS6 …)

Answer (score 0):

`.a` files from Unix are like `.lib` files in Windows. They will not work, and there is no way of "converting" them, short of using a compiler on the original source code.

However, Boost does build on Windows. Just download it (or more likely, the closest version you can find to the one your code was using).

Older versions of Boost did work under VS6, but with a whole lot of stuff disabled (VS6 really just *barely* qualified as a C++ compiler). If you can, I highly suggest you use a newer version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.  Building Boost will give you the greatest flexibility in working with your application and boost libraries.  However, you can download pre-built Boost libraries wrapped up in a nice windows installer here, [Boost Packages](http://www.boostpro.com/download)

But one thing to keep in mind, depending on what you used in Boost, a lot of it is template based so no libraries are required.  If you're only using some templatized portions, you don't need to worry about any of this.  Just make sure you have boost in your include path when building.

As a side note, you can get free but limited versions of newer MS compilers here: http ://www.microsoft.com/exPress/